# How to show alert from code behind after page loads completely?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am showing alert at button click and have tab control at page . Alert appears but tab disappears at alert. I want to show alert so that tab will not disappear at alert. Is there any technique how to handle this thing ?

```
<asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0">
<asp:TabPanel ID="pael1" HeaderText="IP text" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:TabPanel>
<asp:TabPanel ID="panel2" HeaderText="text" runat="server">  
    <ContentTemplate>
       // Button Click Event
    </ContentTemplate>
     </asp:TabPanel>
</asp:TabContainer>

protected _Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "Message", "alert('Connection Successful!')", true);
        }
```

Comment: Which alert? JavaScript? You marked your question as C# and ASP.Net. It would also be useful to have some code to understand exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: can you not use JavaScript to do the alert before the post back then the page and everything it contains will remain.

Comment: @AndreCruz Yes `JavaScript` alert.

Comment: @user3374409 In my scenario I want to show alert at `ButtonClick` Event

Comment: @AndreCruz I have posted code too. kindly review.

Comment: @user2178738 Can you paste the whole code?

Comment: @AndreCruz what else is required please ?

Comment: @user2178738 It's not clear how the click event is fired. Is that all the code you have in your page? What do you mean by "tab disappears"? Let me see if I understand the scenario: You have a page with multiple sub-tabs. You then click on a tab and it becomes VISIBLE. You then click a button somewhere, which causes a post-back, and then when the page is redisplayed the tab which was visible becomes invisible, so that you need to click on the tab again to show it. Is that the case? If so, this is a more fundamental issue. Why do you need to cause a postback?

Comment: You may want to maintain state and force a last visited tab to be re-displayed, or something like that.

Comment: @AndreCruz Sir Tabs are working perfect and my problem is not actually related to them. In one of the tab I have button and its onClick propert . Once I click the button I want to show alert from code behind code which I have mentioned in my code. My issue is when I click on button alert appears but whole tab container disappears automatically ad when i click on Ok of alert it appears again. I want ot to disappear Tab Container at button click which is inside one of the tab

Comment: @user2178738 are you using jquery?

Comment: @AndreCruz No, I am not using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should be using the following command according to the MSDN website (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy(v=vs.110).aspx):

Note: the script should be within `<script></script>`.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "Message", "<script type=text/javascript>alert('Connection Successful!');</script>", true);
```

The script is added to the top of your page, before the content, so the alert is displayed before your page is rendered. In order to fix this issue, use:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "Message", "<script type=text/javascript>window.onload = function(){alert('Connection Successful!');}</script>", true);
```

By doing so, you ensure that only when the page (JavaScript `window` object) loads the alert is displayed.

If you are using jquery, you can also use:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "Message", "<script type=text/javascript>$(window).load(function() {alert('Connection Successful!');});</script>", true);
```

Comment: the last parameter of function `RegisterStartupScript` takes a bool value whether to add script tags or not. If you are already sending `true` then there's no need adding <script> tags in your script

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "mykey", "alert('"+ ex.Message +"');", true);
```